# Can $p^{q-1}\equiv 1 \pmod {q^3}$ for primes $p<q$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For prime $q$ can it be that
$$
p^{q-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{q^k}
$$
for some prime $p<q$ and for $k\ge 3$?

There doesn't seem to be a case with $k=3$ and $q<90000$, and I also checked for  small solutions with $3<k\le 20$ and found none.

If we remove the condition $p<q$ then there are always solutions, e.g. $15441^{16}\equiv 1 \pmod{17^5}$. Also for $k=2$ there are many, e.g. $71^{330} \equiv 1 \pmod {331^2}$.

Comment: I don't know. Agree about removal of condition $p\lt q$, use Hensel lifting and the Dirichlet theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: Short Pari/GP command line for probing more $q$ (adjust the range for $q$): `k=3;forprime(q=3,1000,g=znprimroot(q^k)^(q^(k-1));h=g;for(j=1,q-2,p=lift(h);if(p<q && ispseudoprime(p), print(p," ",q));h*=g))`

Comment: @Zander: Do you really mean $3< k\leq 20$ or $3< p \leq 20$? Testing higher $k$ when nothing is found for $k=3$ seems to make no sense to me.

Comment: If the requirement "$p$ prime" is dropped, there is precisely one $1<p<q\leq 100000$ with prime $q$, namely $(p,q)=(68,113)$ with $k=3$.

Comment: @ccorn Hmm, strange why the primality of $p$ should enter into this. Makes me suspicious a large counterexample may exist.

Comment: @user7530 I don't think the primality plays much of a role. It's just that it's anyway unlikely that the remainder of $a^{q^2}$ modulo $q^3$ falls into the range $1 < r < q-1$ for $1 < a < q-1$, and since composites are much more frequent than primes, it is to be expected that there are more incidences for composites, and you find several such before you find the first prime incident.

Comment: Assuming (without proof) the heuristics associated with Daniel Fischers argument, I figure that, given $q^k$, the probabilistic density of suitable $p$ is about $\frac{1}{q^{k-2}\log q}$. For fixed $k>3$ this indicates that the number of suitable $(p,q^k)$ pairs should be finite. For $k=3$ an infinite number of solutions seems "not implausible". Still searching, yet nothing found for $q$ up to $347000$.

Comment: @ccorn Only primes, or any $a < q$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: No $p$ with $1<p<q$, not even nonprime $p$, except for the early-found $(p,q^k)=(68,113^3)$.

Comment: Update: No further $p$  with $1<p<q$, not even nonprime $p$, for all prime $q$ up to $2642239$, that is, $q^3<2^{64}$

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594708/fermat-quotient-of-order-3-i-found-68112-equiv-1-pmod-1133-are-th and also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151047/fermat-quotient-of-order-3-i-found-68112-equiv-1-pmod-1133-are-th

Comment: For the infinitude of solutions when $p \lt q$ is removed and for the general case where p is not prime this heuristical article might be interesting http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquot_ge2_table1.htm

Comment: Im surprised this has no answer !

Answer (score -1):

Let $w>1$ be any integer and let $q$ be an odd prime and $w^{q-1}$  $\equiv 1 \pmod {q^3}$. Let v be a primitive root mod $q^3$ where $v^h$  $\equiv w \pmod {q^3}$. So $v^{h(q-1)}$  $\equiv 1\pmod {q^3}$. Therefore h=$q^2 k$ ; k >= 1. Assume k> 1 , then $w^{(q-1)/k}$ $\equiv 1\pmod {q^3}$ ; $v^{q^2 k-k}$ $\equiv(w/v^k) \pmod {q^3}$ , so $v^{(q^2 k -k)(q^2)}$ $\equiv 1 \pmod {q^3}$ ,therefore $(w/v^k)^{q^2}$  $\equiv 1\pmod {q^3}$. If the order of w mod $q^3$ is M then given $(w/v)^{q^2 M} $ $ \equiv 1 \pmod {q^3}$ ; $v^{q^2 M}$ $\equiv 1 \pmod {q^3}$. Yet this implies M = (q-1).  Then the order of w mod $q^3$ is  not <(q-1) contradiction. So k = 1. And $v^{q^2}$ $\equiv w \pmod q^3$. The order of w mod $q^3$ is (q-1). If w = p a prime < q then $p^{q-1}$ $\equiv 1 \pmod {q^3}$ where (q-1) is the order of p. p = (q-v);  $(q-v)^q$ $\equiv(q-v)\pmod {q^3}$. So ($q^2$ $v^{q-1}$ -$v^q$) $\equiv(q-v)\pmod {q^3}$. Therefore $v^{q-1}$ ($q^2$-v) $\equiv (q-v)\pmod{q^3}$ ;  $(-v q)\equiv (q^2-v q)\pmod{q^3}$ ; $q^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{q^3}$ Contradiction , so if p < q the order of p mod $q^3$ can not be (q-1)

Comment: Where have you used the hypothesis that the variables are to be prime? How do you account for the examples in the question and comments?

Comment: Moreover, where did $w^{(q^4+1)/(w+1)}$ come from? You aren't asserting $$q^4+1=(q+1)(q^3-q^2+q-1)$$ are you?

Comment: Sorry ,I should have said; let q^4 =U  ,w^U=W mod (q^3). So (q^4-q^3+q^2-q+1)= Y ; w^Y =1 mod q^3 ; ((q^5)+1)/(q+1) =b , w^b=1 mod q^3, w^(q^5 + 1) =1 mod q^3 and w^(q^5-1) = 1 mod q^3.Therefore w^2 =1 mod q^3

Comment: I reformatted your answer so I could read it, but I can't reformat comments. Please see how I edited your answer, and repost your comment in legible form. Or if your comment is meant to be a correction to your answer, then please edit it in to your answer (with proper formatting).

Comment: Firstly, I think you mean $\frac{q^5+1}{q+1}$, not $\frac{q^5+1}{w+1}$. Secondly, I think you mean $q^4-q^3+q^2-q+1=T$, since that is $\frac{q^5+1}{q+1}$. Thirdly, $w^T\equiv w$ mod $q^3$: how do you get that to be $\equiv 1$? Lastly, how are $u,v,y$ relevant?

Comment: u,v,y are just representations of exponents to some exponents. I can't use your algebra inputting methods well enough. I guess this attempted answer is not going anywhere.

Comment: I rewrote my 'answer' , if that count's for anything..

Comment: I think my recent rewriting answers the problem..