# Fermat-quotient of "order" 3: I found $68^{112} \equiv 1 \pmod {113^3}$ - are there bigger examples known?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, numerical-methods, prime-numbers

I'm rereading an older text on fermat-quotients (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_quotient)) from which I have now the

***Question*** for
$$ b^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{ p^m} \qquad \text{ with $p \in \mathbb P $, $1 \lt b \lt p$ and $m \gt 2$} $$ 
(This is a generalization of the question for Wieferich primes).

Note that I ask here for examples, where the bases $b$ are *smaller* than the prime $p$, so a very well known weaker case $3^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod {11^2 } $ were an example, but only if the exponent at $11$ where one more; however frequent and well known cases like $18^6 \equiv 1 \pmod {7^3} $ were not because the base is bigger than the prime.

The only example that I've found so far is
$$ 68^{112} \equiv 1 \pmod {113^3 } $$
but I've scanned only the first *2000* primes $p \in (3 \ldots 17389)$ and my primitive brute force algorithm has more than quadratic time-characteristic, so checking *10 000* or *100 000* primes were no fun - the quadratic regression prognoses *1* hour for testing *10 000* primes and *101* hours for testing *100 000* primes...

I'm aware of a couple of webpages containing lists of fermat quotients up to much higher primes, but either there is no explicite mention of the cases of $b \lt p$ and quotient $m \gt 2$ or I've been too dense when scanning through the listings ([Richard Fischer](http://www.fermatquotient.com/), [Wilfrid Keller](http://www1.uni-hamburg.de/RRZ/W.Keller/FermatQuotient.html), [Michael Mossinghoff](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~mjm/WieferichBarker/))

---

For reference: my Pari/GP-code is

```
for(j=2,2000,p=prime(j);p3=p^3;
    for(k=2,p-1,
        r = lift(Mod(k,p3)^(p-1));
        if(r==1,print(p," ",k," ",r)));
    );
```

P.s. I've no real good idea for tagging of this question; I just tried the most similar...

Comment: Your "p3=p1^3" line of code should be "p3=p^3", yes?

Comment: @matth: yepp. corrected.Typical error when adapting/formatting code for the wider audience...;-)

Comment: I ran your code to j=10000 and found no more solutions.

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456744/can-pq-1-equiv-1-pmod-q3-for-primes-pq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MO there was an answer indicating, that there shall be no more information than that of Richard Fischer's site, where he lists, that indeed that pair $(68,113)$ is the only pair up to about $p \le 3.6 \cdot 10^6$ and where also $b \lt p$ which gives a fermat-quotient greater than *2* , so I think I should "close the case" here.

For the casual reader I'll add a link to a more explanative description of the problem and my empirical table. See [here](http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquot_ge2_table1.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Let:

$$a \equiv \frac{1+p+(1-p)i\sqrt{3}}{2} \pmod{p^m}$$
$$b \equiv \frac{1+p-(1-p)i\sqrt{3}}{2} \pmod{p^m}$$

Solve $y,z$:

$$z(a-1) \equiv y(1-p) \pmod{p^m}$$
$$y(b-1) \equiv z(1-p) \pmod{p^m}$$

which gives $n \equiv z/y \pmod{p^m}$:

Then:

$$n^{p-1} \equiv (n+1)^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^m}$$

Example 1:

$$p=2^{1279}-1$$
$$m=3$$

$n=$
4193448058206682873621824158021428679822550264847282456793752295957175
3153442074548686582960823865273862518541720310579907212741969013146701
0908225904821914113440262402897252716384202357038181584666254723949487
8239938474907368439981649584477919165028110884789434323006066188241345
1463124763450131423829445760508363230626005791363150628815155877642553
4987566365695364600582000409773803975118909343165162752704607450659074
3806221546068991416529999466945128099034455166089347840467896750227418
8384770724100668469462477683273584346835056282474386449209051044152369
5393682003954734942756855911437108390360251029572746951614332639385620
4184442797278233950092436333792610135182474868900587898393818528343569
4511113155133062921850192766346290415309472473005040083413550832807665
4190597302596327445361381998810963186857119186502017546545746031695425
2241339077896318309124505605093791885920854502257584415732910882974834
5475820163487644065397627422527894342424088084184985066014407179728024
5738698581633381467677449683445931614429170801716228186331336053666675
6635091621791635780644015994145735910114211793789834588664248165166892
79323686166599763440605295738148494

Then $n^{p-1} \equiv (n+1)^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^3}$

Example 2:

$$p=2^{3217}-1$$
$$m=2$$

$n=$24169923838852617528407811160580997579931635145436429097006296362574483206392750161196679884292142731378759972457570738149490352500317875977202589390081836217844616087112510805145389735536612232004991805501828296126959470151987865578388499386259623018083904239950356081139169177543595728862464781491222106794887952637075293360128014937872115729078227625737712745323497803157790062909627916915955813614973352099964950762104633501116353416150046245401878399864761794396240552448046561703177352146844234630239924672444077553319531288270869470057562339056734824188152712295704682112679849388663784604583105820503263100049638100550970039726314508760040945808420211214551667874496135873229360299894699105500629224274103194968523400671500415299328714741111005971276011195129070307603233610298855595026078168962145872902649618986554828497068957149293249333809896944711083929987949964782684917837738389953316363386356195461995142647935178758948113766475124125153551001973422084668079695481167089638951090169976304934335410858519576999493466151741286159527314352402379920657667108204360732281783834661390377507459240720062670510011591244697525836414215597549941776059148666073939224949000789931725868105621153363276851920635964164371507034487466894542861872245430608894427876173362899029852396945958921493344816626010077856394498252056931986015483787263710740457837973079714379084797583658753193727067032891124387408532800940428244442725275961163004772675000704045418995762335986928493775805279058463749832204884571896980776416860410796167576657288198073311777805248399762198978804586931478439571896249546511463022721380472366586175514061598041479212997482456441191477716555533111296652012735526087952080739209158309719708459357370094913135259062933831298486150982237595383212183720894169053431622606219824209717219748477604211220630078786353257863190141858844049982646213667215855499496318644796746659140633598872928747671878528613671294130685111

Then $n^{p-1} \equiv (n+1)^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$

This was derived from my question(which has not received any answers):

[Question about p-adic numbers related to Fermat's last theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803001/question-about-p-adic-numbers-related-to-fermats-last-theorem)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just checked with Pari/GP. Seems to work - congrats! Do you have some more significant properties of $b$? (and -of course- would you mind to describe how you found that number?)

Comment: However note, that here $b \gt p$ which, as far as I recall (before rereading my text) was the somehow "easier" cases when I've analyzed the problem of high fermat quotients - my couriosity has been on the *very rare cases* where $b \lt p$. I'll reread my relevant notes later. Anyway - thanks again for this big number example!